# Django default language

Tags: django, internationalization

I have a django application which has default language set to French.
All translation strings in the code and html pages are in french. Switching between differents language works fine.
But now I need to hide french language, so I changed LANGUAGE_CODE to 'en-us', but default page always displays in french, did I miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: try to change your browser local language, may be it helps

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: This is a bug in Django, as far as I'm concerned. It is simply incorrect to assume that users of all language cultures have their browsers configured to their native language. Users still expect their language-specific websites to be in their language.

Answer (score 10):

I faced this problem just recently, here's how I could manage to fix it without changing any browser's locale language:

the idea is to create a middleware to force language translation based on the LANGUAGE_CODE setting, here's how the middleware might look like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import translation

class ForceLangMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.LANG = getattr(settings, 'LANGUAGE_CODE', settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
        translation.activate(request.LANG)
        request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.LANG
```

save this snippet as middleware.py in your main app (I assume it's called main) and then add main.middleware.ForceLangMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Answer (score 5):

i found this https://gist.github.com/vstoykov/1366794 . It forces I18N machinery to choose settings.LANGUAGE_CODE as the default initial language.

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble with this too once... It's because most modern web-browsers send their locale setting in the request, and Django automatically uses that language instead if it can.

Unfortunately I don't remember what I did to solve this, but I hope it gives you some pointers where to look or search for.

Comment: Thanks, it was the issue, solved by changing browser locale language

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py file you have a [`LANGUAGES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#languages) tuple.

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('sv', gettext('Swedish')),
    ('no', gettext('Norwegian')),
)
```

If you're using [Django Multilingual](http://django-multilingual.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/_build/html/overview.html), you can also set `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` setting:

```
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1 # the first one in the list
```

Comment: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE does not seem to work for me, and this variable is not referenced in [django settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/)

Comment: what version of Django are you running at the moment?

Comment: `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` is a `django_multilingual` setting; ApPeL was probably using that and then mistook it for a Django setting: http://django-multilingual.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/_build/html/overview.html